# There has been an error processing your request: Error log record number: d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f

Tags: magento2, php, database, javascript, backup

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f

```
i run the record log number in putty this what i see :
```

var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: tax_class_id: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: final_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: minimal_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: min_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: max_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: tier_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: cat_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: position: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: cat_index_position: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: name: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: image: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: small_image: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: thumbnail: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: name: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: short_description: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: special_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: special_from_date: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: special_to_date: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: image: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: small_image: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: thumbnail: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: news_from_date: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: news_to_date: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: required_options: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: image_label: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: small_image_label: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: thumbnail_label: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: msrp: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: msrp_display_actual_price_type: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: url_key: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: links_purchased_separately: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: links_exist: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_type: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: weight_type: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_view: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: swatch_image: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: tax_class_id: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: sw_featured: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: ordered_qty: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: order: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: state: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: stock_status_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: stock_status: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: is_salable: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: catalog_product_entity: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: e: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: catalog_product_index_price: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: price_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: catalog_category_product_index_store1: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: cat_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: sales_order_item: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: soi: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: sales_order: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: order: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: cataloginventory_stock_status: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: stock_status_index: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: soi: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: product_id: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: ordered_qty: command not found
var/report/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f: lin e 1: 0:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name' in 'field list', query was: SELECT .*, ., ., ., IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LE AST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS , ., ., ., . AS , ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., . , ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., SUM(soi.qty_ordered) AS , ., . AS FROM AS \n INNER J OIN AS ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_i d = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'\n INNER JOIN AS ON cat_index.product_id =e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id=2 AND cat_index. is_parent=1\n LEFT JOIN AS ON soi.product_id = e.entity_id\n INNER JOIN AS O N order.entity_id = soi.order_id\n INNER JOIN AS ON e.entity_id = stock_status _index.product_id WHERE (order.state <> 'canceled' and soi.parent_item_id IS NUL L AND soi.product_id IS NOT NULL) AND (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) GROU P BY . ORDER BY DESC\n LIMIT 3: command not found

Answer (score 0):

you must have enter incorrect column name, or while inserting data you must have wrong filed data. please check once and you will good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `cat var/reports/d11d948cb3596b359566fa162df65dbf6baef2446fe384f4476057675f3dd95f` in your project root directory. Connect to your server with ssh. In your case with putty. Then, navigate to your project root and run the command. Then you will see the error message, magento wrote in the report.
I'm not sure, what exactly you did to get this wired output. I think: you tried to execute the report as a command. You have to use a command (like `cat`) to output the file.